# Reducing a particular fraction

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have stumpled upon the following and I can't figure out how the two are equivalent. What steps are required to go from the first to the second?

$$
c(t+1) = \frac{t-1}{t} \> c(t) + \frac{1}{t} \> x(t)
$$

$$
c(t+1) = c(t) + \frac{1}{t+1} \> (x(t) - c(t))
$$

**EDIT:**
It's from [this](http://www.heikohoffmann.de/htmlthesis/node134.html) site, and I rewrote it as specified there. Shouldn't it be like that?

Comment: $\frac{t-1}{t} =1-\frac{1}{t} $

Comment: As stated these are not equivalent.  The first has a discontinuity at $t=0$ and the second has a discontinuity at $t = -1$.

Answer (score 0):

The fraction $\frac 1{1+t}$ is not correct. It should be $\frac 1t$.

Comment: I have added the source where I got it from. Is that correct?